# Php select onchange doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, php, html, onchange

I was having an issue with some code I had so I am starting again from scratch, but now something that was working in my original code is not working here and I can not figure out why. When I make a selection from the dropdown box the onchange function, which should trigger my reload function, nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require 'config.php';  // Database connection
//////// End of connecting to database ////////
?>
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    function reload(form)
    {
        var val=form.year1.options[form.year.options.selectedIndex].value;
        self.location='spt.php?year1='+val;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <?Php
    @$year1=$_GET['year1'];
    @$team1=$_GET['team1'];

    $quer1="SELECT DISTINCT year FROM PlayerRegSeason ORDER BY year";
    $quer2="SELECT DISTINCT team FROM PlayerRegSeason WHERE year=$year1 ORDER BY team";
    $quer3="SELECT fname, lname FROM PlayerRegSeason WHERE year=$year1 and team ='$team1'";

    echo "<form method=post name=f1 action ='searchpageresultsdd.php'>";

    echo "<select name ='year1' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select Year</option>";
    foreach ($dbo->query($quer1) as $row1){
        if($row1['year']==@$year1){echo "<option selected value='$row1[year]'>$row1[year]</option>"."<BR>";}
        else{echo "<option value='row1[year]'>$row1[year]</option>";}
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>` => `<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">`

Comment: Thanks fred, but unfortunately that did not do it.

Comment: I know, just pointing out missing quotes, which you should also be doing for `method=post name=f1`. Some browsers do **not** like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `name` attribute of the `<select>` tag is `year1`, this syntax

```
var val=form.year1.options[form.year.options.selectedIndex].value;
```

should be changed to this

```
var val=form.year1.options[form.year1.options.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was fairly confident I missed something dumb and that was it.